# How to move large amounts of mail with PHP?

Tags: php, email, imap

I'm trying to write a PHP program that uses the IMAP PHP extension to run through a very large inbox (greater than 70,000 emails), and move all emails that fall within a specified date range into a folder.  I keep running into problems trying to get the mail that falls within the desired range.

First I tried using the SINCE and BEFORE criteria in imap_search() to place all of the desired ID numbers into an array, and then created a string listing these ID numbers to feed into imap_mail_move().  But the problem I keep running into is that imap_search() never actually returns all of the emails within the specified range.  For instance, I ran the following code:

```
    echo "Beginning search. \n";
    $mail = imap_search($this->mbox, 
                   'SINCE "$startDate" BEFORE "$endDate"');
    echo "Search complete. \n";
    if (!$mail){echo "The inbox is empty. \n"; die();}

    $count = 0;
    foreach($mail as $i)
    {
        $count = $count + 1;
    }
    echo "Found $count emails. \n";
```

while specifying a date range that I know to hold 600ish emails, and imap_search() only listed 259 of them.  When I expanded the range to encompass the entire inbox of about 75,000 emails, imap_search() only returned 25,112 of them.

When this didn't work, I tried a different, slower way to get all emails within the desired date range.  I used imap_search() to collect ALL emails in the inbox, then I iterated through each email, compared the date contained in the emails header to the dates definining my interval, and added the ID to a string if it was in range.  I ran the following code:

```
    // Get all mail in the INBOX
    $mail = imap_search($this->mbox, "ALL");
    if (!$mail){echo "The inbox is empty. \n"; die();}

    // Create a string list of all message IDs 
    //that fall in the specified range
    $processed = 0;
    $IDsequence = '';
    foreach($mail as $messageID)
    {
        $date = imap_headerinfo($this->mbox, $messageID)->date;
        try {$dateObject = new DateTime($date);}
        catch (Exception $e) {echo $e->getMessage(); echo "\n";}
        $dateObject->setTimezone($TimeZone); 
        if ($dateObject <= $IntervalEndDate && $dateObject >=
                          $IntervalStartDate)
        {
            $IDsequence = $IDsequence . "," . strval($messageID);
        }
        $processed = $processed + 1;
        if ($processed % 100 == 0)
        { echo "Processed $processed emails. \n"; }

    }
    // If we got at least one message, cut off the first comma.
    if (strlen($IDsequence) > 1){
        $IDsequence = substr($IDsequence, 1, strlen($IDsequence)-1);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No e-mail to move. \n";
        die();
    }
    echo "Beginning copy. \n";
    imap_mail_copy($this->mbox, $IDsequence, $TargetFolder);
    echo "Copy complete. \n";
    //imap_expunge($this->mbox);
    imap_close($this->mbox);
```

After iterating through just over 25,000 emails, it began to print the error message  'object does not exist' referencing the line of code where I collect the date from the email header.  I notice here that the breakdown still occurs somewhere around 25,000 emails, so perhaps both methods break for the same reason.  I suspect that I am doing something wrong with the message IDs (for instance, I am assuming that the message IDs for the 75,000 emails are '1' through '75,000').

What is going wrong?  Is there a way to collect a large number of emails that fall within a date range and move them?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there are only 25,112 messages in the mailbox, and the other ~50,000 are in another mailbox. I know GMail, for example, may report a rough total for the Inbox, but a good percentage of those messages are actually archived.

You might want to do a sanity check at this point. :)

Comment: I don't think that's the case here.  I counted the elements returned when I ran imap_search($mbox, "ALL"), and counted the full size of the inbox.  I guess things just begin to go wrong at around 25,000 when I try sorting by date.